# MS ACCESS SELECT Query merge columns from many tables

Tags: sql, select, ms-access-2010

I have 4 tables:

1. Main (ID (KEY), A1_ID, A2_ID, A3_ID);
2. A1 (A1_ID (KEY), NameA1);
3. A2 (A2_ID (KEY), NameA2);
4. A3 (A3_ID (KEY), NameA3);

You need a query to get the following table:

```
Main.ID, A1.NameA1, A2.NameA2, A3.NameA3 
where Main.ID for example = 12
```

Thank you in advance for your cooperation

Comment: Small clarification. In the table Main fields A1_ID, A2_ID, A3_ID сan be equal NULL.

Comment: If those fields can be NULL then they can't be Primary Keys.  The PRIMARY KEY constraint uniquely identifies each record in a database table.  Primary keys must contain UNIQUE values, and cannot contain NULL values. A table can have only one primary key, which may consist of single or multiple fields. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should use JOINs to join those tables.

```
SELECT Main.ID
    ,A1.NameA1
    ,A2.NameA2
    ,A3.NameA3
FROM Main
INNER JOIN A1 ON Main.A1_ID = A1.A1_ID
INNER JOIN A2 ON Main.A2_ID = A2.A2_ID
INNER JOIN A3 ON Main.A3_ID = A3.A3_ID
WHERE Main.ID = 12
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay. Small clarification. In the table Main fields A1_ID, A2_ID, A3_ID сan be equal NULL.

Comment: Access won't like those joins - it just loves to have brackets.  It'll need two opening brackets before `Main`, one closing after `=A1.A1_ID` and the other after `=A2.A2_ID`.